# LiveCamera xamarin.IOS and Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to set up a camera management feature natively on Xamarin.
I have a particular feature to implement modifying the image before rendering on the Camera.

For the Android version I use OnSurfaceTextureAvailable which allows me to modify an image before rendering.

At Ios I'm stuck I don't know where to start if someone could help me!!!!

To read you

For the IOS version I use the AVCaptureSession , AVCaptureDeviceInput , AVCaptureStillImageOutput , UIView object but I don't know how to define a method that allows to modify the image before displaying

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation [*Manual Camera Controls in Xamarin.iOS*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/intro-to-manual-camera-controls) and [*ManualCameraControls sample*](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/ManualCameraControls), we could take control of some camera features, such as **Manual Focus**, **Manual Exposure** and **Manual White Balance**.

If you used xamarin.forms, [*Customizing a ContentPage*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage) and [*CameraPageRenderers Samples*](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/ContentPage) are also recommended.

For example, I tried setting the white balance value when using camera :

```
void ConfigureCameraForDevice (AVCaptureDevice device)
    {
        
        var error = new NSError ();
        if (device.IsWhiteBalanceModeSupported(AVCaptureWhiteBalanceMode.ContinuousAutoWhiteBalance))
        {
            device.LockForConfiguration(out error);  
            device.WhiteBalanceMode = AVCaptureWhiteBalanceMode.ContinuousAutoWhiteBalance;
            var TempAndTint = new AVCaptureWhiteBalanceTemperatureAndTintValues(1000, -100); // i set this value at random

            // Convert Color space
            var gains = device.GetDeviceWhiteBalanceGains(TempAndTint);

            // Set the new values

            gains = NomralizeGains(gains,device);
            device.SetWhiteBalanceModeLockedWithDeviceWhiteBalanceGains(gains, null);
            device.UnlockForConfiguration();
        }
```

You could find the relevant code in [*CameraPageRenderers Samples*](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/CustomRenderers/ContentPage) and
[*ManualCameraControls sample*](https://github.com/xamarin/ios-samples/tree/main/ManualCameraControls)

Hope my answer works for you.

Comment: Does my answer make sense or if you still have any question?